# Angular 8 / Typescript set Property of Interface when calling data

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

So I an calling this in angular

```
 savePat(obj: PatientData): Observable<IJsonSaveResult> {
    return this.http.post<IJsonSaveResult>(`${environment.serviceUrl}/patients/addpatient`, obj);
  }
```

my IJsonSaveResult is

```
export interface IJsonSaveResult {
    success:    boolean;
    errors:     any[];
    resultSet: any;

}
```

resultSet can be anything but i want to type it similar to .Net Generics

```
savePat(obj: PatientData): Observable<IJsonSaveResult(PatientData)> {
        return this.http.post<IJsonSaveResult>(`${environment.serviceUrl}/patients/addpatient`, obj);
      }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript generics are remarkably similar to C# generics (no surprise, since Microsoft is behind Typescript).

You would declare the type of the `resultSet` as a generic parameter on the `IJsonSaveResult` interface:

```js
export interface IJsonSaveResult<TResultSet> {
  success: boolean;
  errors: any[];
  resultSet: TResultSet;
}
```

And call it like this:

```js
savePat(obj: PatientData): Observable<IJsonSaveResult<PatientData>> {
  const url = `${environment.serviceUrl}/patients/addpatient`;
  return this.http.post<IJsonSaveResult<PatientData>>(url, obj);
}
```

Comment: I avoid Angular Material whenever possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you could do something like:

```
export interface IJsonSaveResult<T> {
    success:    boolean;
    errors:     any[];
    resultSet: T[];
}
```

And then:

```
savePat(obj: PatientData): Observable<IJsonSaveResult<PatientData>> {
    return this.http.post<IJsonSaveResult<PatientData>>(`${environment.serviceUrl}/patients/addpatient`, obj);
}
```